# Spices and Baking

Tags: baking

I'm new to this cooking thing and I would like to stock my cabinet with the general spices and different season's that someone might use everyday in cooking....can you help with a list of most commonly used spices?

Comment: Are you looking for baking, cooking or both? And is there anything you especially like to cook? As it is, the question is quiet vague, and therefore hard to answer (Putting Mint into a cake MAY work in rare circumstances, but usually, it is a bad fit. Adding some Mint to anything fruity? Usually, awesomeness ^^)

Comment: There are hundreds of spices and herbs, you need to narrow your question down. What cuisines do you want to cook?

Comment: You may want to start with your country of origin or the country whose cuisine you are most familiar with.

Comment: For example, in the USA, I'd start with parsley, sage, rosemary, thyme, cumin, coriander, dill, paprika, basil.  Parsley and basil are much better fresh, so not something generally used from a bottle.  See here as well: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/what-herbs-and-spices-should-a-beginner-cook-have

Comment: Hello Cathy! I'm glad to hear that you are starting with cooking, it's a nice hobby. But our site is not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site. With time, we noticed that certain types of question don't work well with our format. "List of common " somethings is such a type of question. So I'm sorry, but I have to close your question. This is not a punishment for you, and you are still welcome to ask other questions. You can read the [Help center](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more what type of questions we accept.

Comment: I'll repeate what I said years ago on the now-closed question that James referenced -- if you're just starting out, stick with spice blends so you don't end up getting spices that just sit in the back of your cabinet for years.  (exact selection based on what you cook, but stuff like adobo, italian seasoning, curry powder, za'atar blend, montreal steak seasoning, mrs. dash, etc.  Even seasoned salt has its place as you're starting out)

Comment: The Question says "BAKING"... And, personally, because I want my spices for baking fresh, I generally buy them in small amounts out of the bulk section at our grocery. It's usually cheaper anyway, and I know they've not been sitting around for two years because they have a packaging date on the sticker from the scale.

Answer (score 1):

For cooking, salt, (sea salt if you prefer it) seasoned salt, whole peppercorns and a grinder.
For seafood we like Old Bay or Tony Cachere's seasoning. Chili powder, cayenne pepper, dried red pepper flakes, a jar of roasted red peppers, basil pesto. 
Dried herbs (or grow your own if you have a green thumb), basil for tomato sauces, garlic and oregano.
For baking, cinnamon (also good in oatmeal), nutmeg (also good in a white sauce), but just a tiny amount, cardamom, and allspice.
Search the internet, or find a cookbook that suits the style of cooking you would like to try, by looking through them you will get a good idea of the spices, seasonings, etc. you would like to cook with.

Good Luck and have fun. Don't be afraid to experiment!